# apache solr error: HTTP 500; /usr/local/solr/example/solr/data/index/segments_15qc (Permission denied)

Tags: 7, debugging, search

I just noticed that my website apache solr doesn't work any more, but I didn't touch my website for a while. When I tried to delete my solr index, I got this error message:

> HTTP 500; /usr/local/solr/example/solr/data/index/segments_15qc (Permission denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/solr/example/solr/data/index/segments_15qc (Permission denied) at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method) at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:241) at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.(FSDirectory.java:441) at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:306) at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.write(SegmentInfos.java:388) at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.prepareCommit(SegmentInfos.java:827) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.startCommit(IndexWriter.java:4570) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommit(IndexWriter.java:3414) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3485) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.closeInternal(IndexWriter.java:1873) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1812) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1776) at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:144) at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.closeWriter(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:179) at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:411) at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:85) at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processCommit(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:154) at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:190) at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:79) at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:58) at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatc: /usr/local/solr/example/solr/data/index/segments_15qc (Permission denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/solr/example/solr/data/index/segments_15qc (Permission denied) at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method) at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241) at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:441) at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:306) at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.write(SegmentInfos.java:388) at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.prepareCommit(SegmentInfos.java:827) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.startCommit(IndexWriter.java:4570) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.prepareCommit(IndexWriter.java:3414) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.commitInternal(IndexWriter.java:3485) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.closeInternal(IndexWriter.java:1873) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1812) at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.close(IndexWriter.java:1776) at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.close(SolrIndexWriter.java:144) at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.closeWriter(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:179) at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.commit(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:411) at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processCommit(RunUpdateProcessorFactory.java:85) at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processCommit(LogUpdateProcessorFactory.java:154) at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.processUpdate(XMLLoader.java:190) at org.apache.solr.handler.XMLLoader.load(XMLLoader.java:79) at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:58) at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:129) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter.java:365) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatc

But I didn't find "/usr/local/solr/example/solr/data/index/segments_15qc" file in the index folder.

Does anyone have any idea? If my setup was wrong, could anyone give some idea that how to set apache solr on drupal 7. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, guys. I found the answer out. I changed the permission for the folder which includes solr-config setting files from 755 to 777. Everything works fine now.

Reference: [Solr Exception](https://www.drupal.org/node/1099320#comment-4236256)